# Unobtrusive Javascript - And Ajax Requests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, validation, razor, unobtrusive-javascript

I've got a simple example here. Basically a form which when submitted will reload itself via an ajax request. The problem is when this happens, the unobtrusive javascript no longer works. I assume I could add the validate and unobtrusive files in the html i get back from the ajax call, but there must be an easier way to re-wire the validators, no?

Notice I'm hijacking my submit button in order to do an AJAX request which will replace the form in the dom, from the html which is returned from the ajax request.

**Model:**

```
    public class Foo
    {
        public int Bar { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller:**

```
public class FooController : Controller
{

    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View(new Foo{});
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Form(Foo model)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Index(Foo model)
    {
        return View();
    }

}
```

**Index.cshtml**

```
@model PartialPostBackValidation.Models.Foo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}

<h2>@Html.ActionLink("Index", "Index")</h2>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    $(function () {
        $("body").on("click", ".ajax-submit", function () {
            var form = $(this).parents("form");
            $.post(
                form.attr("action"),
                form.serialize(),
                function (html) {
                    form.replaceWith(html);
                }
            );
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>


@{Html.RenderPartial("Form");}
```

**Form.cshtml**

```
@model PartialPostBackValidation.Models.Foo

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
    Layout = null;
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("Form", "Foo")) {
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
    <fieldset>
        <legend>Foo</legend>

        <div class="editor-label">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Bar)
        </div>
        <div class="editor-field">
            @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Bar)
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Bar)
        </div>
        <p>
            <input type="submit" value="Create" class="ajax-submit" />
        </p>
    </fieldset>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the validation to work you simply have to re-enable it on the form once content is loaded dynamically:

```
$('#form-id').removeData('validator');
$('#form-id').removeData('unobtrusiveValidation');
$.validator.unobtrusive.parse('#form-id');   <<<<<< Just having this could be enough but some people complain that without removingData first it doesn’t always work.
```

p.s. Ofcourse you're going to need to add an id attribute to your `@using (Html.BeginForm("Form", "Foo"))`

Comment: this is great- it does do the validation-- is there a way to use javascript to see if any of my validators failed?

Comment: With JQuery validate ? if ($('#id').valid()) {"hello world";}